# A* search algorithm heuristic function

Tags: artificial-intelligence, a-star, heuristics

I am trying to find the optimal solution to a Sliding Block Puzzle of any length using the A* algorithm.

The Sliding Block Puzzle is a game with white (W) and black tiles (B) arranged on a linear game board with a single empty space(-). Given the initial state of the board, the aim of the game is to arrange the tiles into a target pattern.

For example my current state on the board is BBW-WWB and I have to achieve BBB-WWW state. 
Tiles can move in these ways :
1. slide into an adjacent empty space with a cost of 1.
2. hop over another tile into the empty space with a cost of 1.
3. hop over 2 tiles into the empty space with a cost of 2.

I have everything implemented, but I am not sure about the heuristic function. It computes the shortest distance (minimal cost) possible for a misplaced tile in current state to a closest placed same color tile in goal state.

Considering the given problem for the current state BWB-W and goal state BB-WW the heuristic function gives me a result of 3. (according to minimal distance: B=0 + W=2 + B=1 + W=0). But the actual cost of reaching the goal is not 3 (moving the misplaced W => cost 1 then the misplaced B => cost 1) but 2.

My question is: should I compute the minimal distance this way and don't care about the overestimation, or should I divide it by 2? According to the ways tiles can move, one tile can for the same cost overcome twice as much(see moves 1 and 2).

I tried both versions. While the divided distance gives better final path cost to the achieved goal, it visits more nodes => takes more time than the not divided one. What is the proper way to compute it? Which one should I use?

Answer (score 1):

It is not obvious to me what an admissible heuristic function for this problem looks like, so I won't commit to saying, "Use the divided by two function."  But I will tell you that the naive function you came up with is not admissible, and therefore will not give you good performance.  In order for A* to work properly, the heuristic used must be admissible; in order to be admissible, the heuristic *must* absolutely always give an optimistic estimate.  This one doesn't, for exactly the reason you highlight in your example.

(Although now that I think about it, dividing by two does seem like a reasonable way to force admissibility.  I'm just not going to commit to it.)

Comment: I'm willing to commit to dividing by 2. The best that you can ever do is move 2 spaces for 1 cost. So dividing by 2 gives you a best case scenario, which will be admissible and consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Your heuristic is not admissible, so your A* is not guaranteed to find the optimal answer every time. An admissible heuristic must never overestimate the cost.

A better heuristic than dividing your heuristic cost by 3, would be: instead of adding the distance D of each letter to its final position, add ceil(D/2). This way, a letter 1 or 2 away, gets a 1 value, 3 or 4 away, gets a 2 value, an so on.